# PHP submit form (for mini web-app) works one page, but doesn't on other (empty $_POST array)?

Tags: php, forms

For my mini web-app I made a registration form and login form. They look same. Difference between two forms is name of input fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<section class="container">
    <div class="login">
        <h1>Prijava za intervju</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="logovanje.php">

            <p><input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Korisnicko ime"></p>
            <p><input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password"></p>

            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Prijava"></p>

        </form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here's PHP simple login code

```
<?php

require_once('databaseClass.php');

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
function logovanje()
{
    *body of function*

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

print_r($_POST);//for testing
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
{
    if ($_POST['user'] !== '' && $_POST['pass'] !== '')
    {
        logovanje();
    }
    else
    {
        echo <<<END
*html page to echo if user and pass are empty*
END;

    }

}
else
{
    echo <<<END
*html page to echo if user and pass are not set*
END;
}
```

The problem is that every time form is submitted, `$_POST` array is empty. That's very strange.

If I change `$_POST['user']` to `$_POST['*anyothername*']` and `$_POST['pass']` to `$_POST['*anyothername*']` then `print_r($_POST)` shows values of 'user' and 'pass' (this behaviour is illogical to me).

Example for username 'test6' and password 'test6':

```
Array ( [user] => test6 [pass] => test6 [commit] => Prijava )
```

And PHP code is:

```
print_r($_POST);//for testing
if (isset($_POST['username111']) && isset($_POST['password222']))
{
```

If I set code right (as it should be):

```
print_r($_POST);//for testing
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
{
```

Then `print_r($_POST)` returns empty array:

```
Array ( )
```

This confuses me a lot. Why would `$_POST` array be empty, when PHP starts executing?

File with same structure, made for registering works without any problems (only difference is that file for registering has function register() instead of logovanje() ).

Comment: goto logovanje.php, first line after <?php write `\var_dump($_POST);`. You can have my car if it's empty :D. Did you do some changes to your configuration?

Comment: I changed some code now.
Did this to see if everything's ok:
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo "DATA <pre>";
var_dump($data);
var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
print_r($_POST);

But still the same. I'm confused that php input is empty?
$_POST can get corrupted, but raw php input? Now I'm really confused.

Comment: It's not ok.
Raw php input is empty.

Now I know why POST array is empty.

But if I change $_POST['user'] to $_POST['anyothername'] and $_POST['pass'] to $_POST['anyothername'] (as I wrote in original question) then code shows both raw php input and populates $_POST array.

Comment: if you exec php from your bash there should be no $_POST and I don't know what stdin is in a server context. I think you don't understand how PHP works with for example apache. do you have apache installed? can your apache take those requests and forward them to php?

Comment: ::1 - - [08/Feb/2015:00:36:44 +0100] "POST /intervju-developing/logovanje.php HTTP/1.1" 302 296 "http://localhost/intervju-developing/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"


This is line from Apache from minute or two ago.
I installed XAMPP on my computer, because my hosting doesn't let me change configuration files.

Comment: there u go. 302 means Found but resource is temporarily found under the URL given at the Location header. And the other thing is, that POST might become a GET. Actually the status code 302 is crap. FInd out why your server is doing that redirection. Maybe some .htaccess rewrite rules?

Comment: I'll look at the issue tommorow. Looks like other page(for registering) is returning 200 which is ok.

Maybe because smarty template that i'm using is not in same folder? Or some smarty problem?

I'll look tommorow. Thought problem may be in code. But totally forgot about configuration :)
Thanks :D

Comment: Hmmm. Yeah. POST becomes GET(seen that in logs). Looks like when PHP goes to isset function (in essence if it tries to access any of $_POST variables) redirect happens? I don't see how is this possible, because Apache routs POST to PHP? And when I change names of $_POST variables (like described in original post) then redirect doesn't happen. Strange. Will look deeper into Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Some other files had bad code :)
And Apache configuration was messed up by someone/something else :)

Aitch, thanks for help :D